# AWS: Using Active-Active failover with weighted routing policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, high-availability, failover

I want to setup an infra on `AWS` with the highest availability possible.
I am considering implementing Active-Active failover with `Route53`'s Weighted Routing policy.

Can this be implemented? Will `Route53` understand when/if a dns is not healthy and stop routing requests to it when using weighted routing policy?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this. You can associate a health check with the routing policy that monitors the end points and then on failure, routes the traffic to the healthy end points.