# AWS: how to configure Active-Active failover using weighted routing policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am considering migrating to Weighted Policy for our Route53 configuration to make out microservice Active/Active. I did comes across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674751/aws-using-active-active-failover-with-weighted-routing-policy) but it doesn't explain how they did this:

If I have LoadBalancers in us-west-2 and us-east-1 and I assign a weighted A record to them in a 50/50 configuration - is that automatically Active Active? Also is weights 50/50 or 100/100?

Comment: Are you implementing health checks? If not, just create one A resource record with multiple IPv4 values. For a good answer, edit your question with more details on what you are trying to achieve and how you are determining a route has gone down. Otherwise, you are just complicating a simple configuration.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

> If I have LoadBalancers in us-west-2 and us-east-1 and I assign a weighted A record to them in a 50/50 configuration - is that automatically Active Active?

Yes, that is correct. An active-active configuration is one where both targets are active, meaning that Route 53 can respond with either of the two.

An active-passive configuration on the other hand is one where both targets are active but Route 53 only responds with the primary.

Further reading:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-types.html

Comment: Thanks. Typically I've read GEOLOCATION/GEOPROXIMITY/LATENCY based work as active/active. I have been trawling the internet to see why 50/50 or 100/100 is not mentioned as ACTIVE/ACTIVE. Is there a reason why its not included in most Active/Active Strategies? Also - is the weight  50/50 or 100/100 to send traffic to either region equally?

Comment: "In active-active failover, all the records that have the same name, the same type, and the same routing policy (incl. weighted) are active unless Route 53 considers them unhealthy. When a resource becomes unavailable, Route 53 can detect that it's unhealthy and stop including it when responding to queries."

Comment: @LesterGray active-active is a logical construct. You can use it with any routing policy as mentioned in the link I shared with you

Comment: @Chris who was that directed towards?

Comment: I just wanted to echo the content of the link you shared. Didn't mean to confuse you :)

Comment: @Chris oh ok, no worries :)

Comment: I've not seen weighted use as an Active/Active before. Any particular reason why it would be more attractive than, say, Latency?